# How is the integral of $\frac{f^\prime}{f}$ being chosen for proofs of the Complex Logarithm and Roots?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, logarithms, radicals

I have been working with some friends to make sense of a proof in Ulrich's *Complex Made Simple*, which follows below:

> **Corollary 4.15.** *Any nonvanishing holomorphic function in a simply connected set has a holomorphic logarithm. That is, if V is simply connected, $f \in H(V)$ and $f$ has no zero in $V$ then there exists $L \in H(V)$ with $$ e^L = f$$ in V.*

> Proof. It follows from Theorem 4.0 [*integral of a holomorphic function over an open set is 0 everywhere if and only if the function is the derivative of some holomorphic function in the open set*] and Theorem 4.14 [Cauchy's Theorem for simply connected sets] that there exists $F \in H(V)$ such that
> $$F^\prime = \frac{f^\prime}{f}. [\text{WHAT IS THIS!?!}]$$
> Now the chain rule show that $(fe^{-F})^\prime =0$, so $fe^{-F}$ is constant. Setting $L = F + C$ for a suitable $c \in \mathbb{C}$ we obtain $fe^{-L} = 1$. $\square$

Now, everything about the proof and it's result makes sense to us, including how you can show, using this idea, that any nonvanishing holomorphic function in a simply connected set has a holomorphic nth root.

The only thing we do not understand is **how they chose their function**. I have seen this pop up in every explanation or proof of this theorem, but I do not believe it is ever addressed as to where this comes from. The only time I have seen it be addressed is in reference to the fact that $f^\prime$ and $f$ are both holomorphic over the set (which we get and that makes sense to us), but never where they come up with the idea to use $\frac{f^\prime}{f}$ as their function for $F^\prime$.

Any help clarifying this would be fantastic!

Comment: If $\log f$ exists as holomorphic function then its derivative is $\frac 1 f f'$. Just differentiate $e^{\log f}=f$.

Comment: Oooooohhhhhhh, okay. Yes, thank you. That makes significantly more sense where this all came from now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I think the hardest part of the problem is brushed over the most.

**Background:** Recall a complex number $z$ can be written as $z=re^{i\theta}$. The angle $\theta$ is the argument and the principle value has the form $Arg\,z\in(-\pi,\pi].$ It can then be shown that
$
\log z=\ln(r)+i(Arg\,z+2k\pi),
$
which is multi-valued. For simplicity, set $k=0$. Then this function fails to be continuous (so not analytic) along the non-positive real axis because the Arg term flips from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, or vice versa.

All of this is to say the following. If the simply connected set $V$ avoids the non-positive real axis, then the logarithm (for any $k$) is analytic inside $V$.

However, suppose $V$ just avoids $z=0$, but may cross through the non-positive real axis. Choose a half-line from the origin that does not cross through $V$. Then we use this half-line as the "bad points," and define the log in such a way that the Arg creates discontinuities at points other than at $\pi$.

For example, suppose $V$ is the open disk of radius $1$, centered at $z=-2$. Then the normal log is not analytic inside this region since it crosses through the non-positive axis. However, define $\log z=\ln(r)+i(Arg^*z +2k\pi)$, where $Arg^*\,z\in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]$. This log fails to be analytic along the non-positive imaginary axis, but is fine in the region $V$.

**In your problem:** The hardest part of the problem is establishing that such a version of log exists for $V$. Since $f$ does not vanish inside $V$, any such definition of $\log f(z)$ that is used will satisfy $f(z)\neq 0$ so, based on what I wrote above, there exists a half-line from the origin such that $f(z)$ avoids this half-line for all $z\in V$.

With all of this background work, it is then pretty routine to calculate the derivative of $\log f(z)$ if we assume $f(z)$ is analytic and $\log$ is analytic inside the region.

EDIT: I guess the proof doesn't really need my analysis, but my analysis provides another interpretation behind why a holomorphic $\log f(z)$ exists.

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much! Learning this stuff over a semester while also learning real anaylsis makes me forget these equivalencies, so this makes the little steps they gloss over a LOT clearer!
I don't know much about graph or category theory, but that explanation makes so much more sense why they chose that function to work with.

Comment: No problem. Complex log is extremely confusing. When the above clicked for me, everything made sense. There's a lot of talk about multi-valued log and sometimes log is analytic, sometimes it isn't. The picture I showed helps to simplify these confusions.

Answer (score 4):

It's the [logarithmic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative).

Comment: THANK YOU!!!
I know this may seem like a simple google search but I think we were so deep in it we couldn't "see the forest for the trees" or something. So thank you, I honestly do not know how we missed this.

Comment: To be fair, the author should have made sure to use the words somewhere, so people could search for it. I dislike the stylistic choice of making a formal mountain out of an intuitive molehill.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you. The author has been using the notation of $\frac{dz}{z}$ to represent this derivative everywhere prior to this proof. So while I understand the reasoning for the shift, for them to do it without any explanation is basically like using new notation randomly without ever addressing it.